# To prove there are no Matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB-BA=kI$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Prove that there are no Matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB-BA=kI$ where $k \ne 0$

Now since the products $AB$ and $BA$ are both defined and a subtraction exists between them so obviously both are square matrices of same order.

Actually i have proved this by considering generic $2\times 2$ matrices.

Letting $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
 c& d
\end{bmatrix}$$

Letting $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
p & q\\ 
 r& s
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now $$AB-BA=\begin{bmatrix}
br-qc & q(a-d)+b(s-p)\\ 
 c(p-s)+r(d-a)& cq-br
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
k & o\\ 
 0& k
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\implies$

$$br-qc=k$$ and

$$br-qc=-k$$

which is not valid unless $k =0$

is there a formal proof?

Comment: No i am pretty sure you will get same equations

Comment: @Ekaver That is right.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Much easier: calculate the trace of both sides...

Answer (score 1):

Take trace....Lhs is 0 Rhs...is not